# How to install Ubuntu from a Ubuntu installation?

Tags: usb, mouse, live-usb

I have installed Ubuntu onto a laptop. I know that I can boot into a liveUSB of Ubuntu and install Ubuntu onto my external hard drive but I was wondering if there is a way to install Ubuntu onto the from within the full installation of Ubuntu. A program like the one that is installed on the liveUSB.
This is due to the track pad on the laptop being broken I have to use a USB mouse receiver to control the mouse. The laptop I'm using only has two USB's so I can't have the mouse plugged in, have the liveUSB and plug in the external harddrive at the same time.
Hope there is a solution to this.

Comment: You can use debbootstrap. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/225693 . For another method see http://askubuntu.com/questions/201521

Answer (score 0):

If you have an sd slot or a dvd, both of those can be made bootable pretty easily. Assuming you don't have either of these the best way would be to ssh into your computer from another and install it on a system that does have a mouse. While I'm sure what you are asking does have a solution, installing from another computer is probably easier.

Answer (score 0):

## grml-rescueboot

This package provides a script for `update-grub` which looks for
Grml ISO images in `/boot/grml` and automatically adds an entry
for each image. The purpose is to use one of those images to
boot a Grml rescue system without using a CD or USB stick.

Download the ISO. Ubuntu CD/DVDs can be downloaded from the official Ubuntu site:
[Ubuntu Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Install `grml-rescueboot`, in the terminal run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grml-rescueboot
```

Place bootable ISO files in the `/boot/grml folder`.

```
sudo mv ~/Downloads/<filename.iso> /boot/grml/
```

Update GRUB

```
sudo update-grub
```

Once the menuentry has been created and GRUB 2 updated, the ISO entry will appear on the GRUB menu during boot

To boot the ISO, highlight the entry, once the ISO is selected from the menuentry additional options such as `Try Me` or `Install` will be presented before booting.

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot)